# Regular Expression in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I'm new in regular expression, and would like to ask help with the problem I have. I had a form, and it has drop down field where user can select one or more values, so the value for that drop down can be Faculty of Arts (if user chose one option) or Faculty of Arts, Faculty of Medicine (if user chose these two from the drop down).

Now, I want to convert this value, so that I can use it to filter my query. I will use this / these value(s) in WHERE clause. In this case, I have to reformat this value to "Faculty of Arts", "Faculty of Medicine", so it will fit in this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE t_faculty IN ("Faculty of Arts", "Faculty of Medicine")
```

A friend of mine suggested me to try regular expression embedded in this SQL statement (I'm using SQL Server for the database). Do you have any idea on how to parse, and embed it in the SQL statement? Basically I need to add " characters in the beginning and end of the string, and replace the ,[space] with ",[space]" to get the wanted result.

Thank you!

Agus

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g column names with odd characters (like `"Column #123"`.) Use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a comma-delimited string within SQL using [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
select * from myTable
where t_faculty in (
    select value from string_split('Faculty of Arts, Faculty of Medicine', ',')
)
```

STRING_SPLIT returns a table of string values that are separated by the delimiter in the input string.

Otherwise you can use several pattern matching functions:

- [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- An SQL CLR (e.g.: C#) function that does expression matching. See [SQL Server Regex](http://eval-sql.net/sql-server-regex).

You may also choose to simply split the string in your app. Then build the appropriate SQL command (or use something like [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) in linq).

Comment: Hi jspcal, Thank you. Will try to use string_split.

Comment: @AgusPrajogo note that for string split you will need to be running  MSSQL version 2016+

Comment: Hi jspcal, yes, just realised that we are using SQL 2008, so I can't use string_split command :D

Comment: Upgrade or use mdq.Split (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633810(SQL.105)) (or https://thefirstsql.com/2011/02/07/regular-expressions-advanced-string-matching-and-new-split-function-sql-server-2008-r2/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use regular expressions here to change the highlighted part of your SQL code :

```
SELECT FROM myTable WHERE t_faculty IN **("Faculty of Arts", "Faculty of Medicine")
```

I think your understanding about the way we use Regular Expressions could be wrong. You generally use regular expressions when you are trying to match with strings in your database which share some common properties. For instance if you have two rows with the fields **"Faculty of Arts 1"** and **"Faculty of Arts 2"**. And you are trying to look up all the rows which have **"Faculty of Arts"** in general, then you could write it as SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE t_faculty LIKE 'Faculty of Arts*' where * would match anything after the text.

Instead of `t_faculty IN (value1,value2)`, you will write something like `t_faculty LIKE 'your regular_expression here'`.

Comment: Hi Rohan, I got the list of faculties from parameter @Faculty, and the format if user select more than one faculties is Faculty of Arts, Faculty of Medicine. Since I want to use this string in my WHERE IN clause, I need to parse it to 'Faculty of Arts', 'Faculty of Medicine' to ensure the query will returned the correct result.. I heard regex can do parsing as well, that's why I'm thinking regex can help me in solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear how you are passing those strings to SQL Server.
And SQL Server delimits strings with single quotes, i.e apostrophes not double quotes.
In whatever client-side code you have access to, simply concatenate the selected strings with apostrophes.
So if a user picks Faculty of Arts and Faculty of Medicine then you can join it all into one long string like

```
"'" & <selected option> & "'" & ",'" & <selected option> & "'"
```

Comment: Hi Youfah, thank you for your reply. I'm editing report built on SSRS, and in this report, it has parameter for the user to choose faculty. User can chose single or multiple faculty.